# Why the following code doesn't run without await keyword?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await

I have a method called `myMethodAsync`, which needs to be executed, make some stuff and then run `DoSomeWork` method - however it doesn't need to wait until the method is done.

It's an asp.net core 2.0 application using Entity Framework Core and the built-in dependency injection. Every class in the sample is Scoped. I'm using repository pattern. There is no error, just nothing is happening If I set breakpoint after `myRepository.GetAsync` or in the `GetAsync` method the debugger doesn't get in.
The code:

```
public async Task myMethodAsync
{
...
await myRepository.AddAsync(entity);
DoSomeWork(id); // If it's lack of await the line below will not works
}

private async Task DoSomeWork(Guid id)
{
  ...
  var someEntity = await myRepository.GetAsync(id); // This line will never be done
}
```

I thought that it's because the `myRepository` is shared somehow, so I extracted the `DoSomeWork` to other class with own `myRepository`, but the effect is the same.

Also If I use `Task.Run` nothing changes.

How do I know that the code is never executed? Beacuse I'm changing the entity and updating it to database later. However the entity is not changed.

Also really intersting is that this following code almost works:

```
public async Task myMethodAsync
{
...
await myRepository.AddAsync(entity);
DoSomeWork(id); // Now it almost works
await myRepository.GetAsync(randomID);
}
private async Task DoSomeWork(Guid id)
{
  ...
  var someEntity = await myRepository.GetAsync(id); // It works now
  ...
  await myRepository.UpdateAsync(entity); // But it doesn't work
}
```

Comment: This is not your real code, it would never compile. `private async DoSomeWork(Guid id)` is an obvious syntax error. among others

Comment: lack of Task, sorry - I was not pasting the code.

Comment: I said it in my question. I want to return the Task and run some background one, beacuse the ````DoSomeWork```` lasts too long and I don't need to wait.

Comment: It seems your repository disposed before running the async method. For running a method backend, you may try `IHostedService`, refer [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: You were right @TaoZhou, but the disposed object is my DbContext. No need to use Hosted services.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution. The problem was with EF - my DbContext was disposed(it didn't throw an exception cause of multi-threading I think). I needed to implement `ICloneable` interface to `DbContext` and `myRepository`. Now I'm passing cloned version of myRepository and everything works fine.

```
public async Task myMethodAsync
{
...
await myRepository.AddAsync(entity);
DoSomeWork(id, (Repository)myRepository.Clone());
}

private async Task DoSomeWork(Guid id, Repository clonedRepository)
{
  ...
  var someEntity = await clonedRepository.GetAsync(id);
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if I should run ````DoSomeWork```` in ````Task.Run````.